# 32bit to 64bit topology errors

Tags: qgis, shapefile, 64bit, personal-geodatabase

Can generating a shapefile from a pgdb cause topology errors due to floating point conversion?  I am running into gaps in a line layer of really small distances (order of 10^-4; CRS EPSG:2227 usft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shapefiles still store numbers using 64 bits of precision, 16-16 digits.  It looks like you need 11 or 12, so you should not get errors unless you are doing computations in which case floating point errors are a remote possiblility.

If anything is ever converted into a 32-bit floating point number you would definitely lose precision.

Comment: Great, thanks,  I wanted to make sure that the gaps were real and not computational artifacts before going through with fixing them.

Comment: You mean *coordinates* use 64 bit precision, numbers as attributes use less digits http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Geoprocessing_considerations_for_shapefile_output

Comment: @user, correct.  Numeric data is stored using dBase IV format (DBF file), which means as strings of digits.